# What does "in the space" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "in this field/area"?

> One of the people said that Apple is developing optical sensors, which
>   involves shining a light through the skin to measure indications of
>   glucose. Accurately detecting glucose levels has been such a challenge
>   that one of the top experts **in the space**, John L. Smith, described it
>   as "the most difficult technical challenge I have encountered in my
>   career." The space is littered with failures, as Smith points out, but
>   that hasn't stopped companies from continuing to attempt to crack this
>   elusive opportunity.
>
> Apple isn't the only technology company eyeing opportunities in the
>   space. Verily, Google's life sciences team, is currently working on a
>   "smart" contact lens to measure blood sugar via the eye, and it
>   partnered up with DexCom in 2015 to develop a glucose-sensing device
>   no bigger than a bandage.

Source: [Apple has a secret team working on the holy grail for treating diabetes](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/12/Apple-working-on-glucose-sensors-diabetes-treatment.html) (CNBC)

Comment: @JavaLatte - I have to disagree; it may be slightly jargonish, but I don't think it's very unconventional at all.  Searches turn up thousands of results like ["Will Microsoft or Google Dominate the Enterprise Collaboration Space?"](http://marketrealist.com/2017/04/will-microsoft-or-google-dominate-the-enterprise-collaboration-space/) or ["Your Best Bet In the Medical Space"](http://www.investopedia.com/stock-analysis/070114/your-best-best-medical-space-xlv-cov-mdt-fxh.aspx)

Comment: @stangdon: Fair enough. I live in a linguistic backwater, and hadn't come across that term before. I have retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means "field", i.e. a particular science, type of study, or industry; or, as @LawrenceC put it, a "community consisting of everyone who is interested in such things and collaborates on related work".

This particular sense is somewhat jargonistic to news speak, though it also occurs in academic work to denote a particular subdivision of a field.

> Professor Anand has carried out important research in the early childhood development space.

There is one definition in the OED that I suspect might have given rise to this meaning:

> *space*, n.1
>   
>  II. Denoting area or extension.
>   
>  * Specific or limited extent.
>   
>  11.
>   
>  **g.** orig. *U.S.* A room or specific area within a building, esp. considered in terms of its function or architectural qualities.

Here's one example under that heading, notable for its connection to work:

> 1981   *N.Y. Times* (Nexis) 8 Feb. d33/1   You have a great space to work with. You have an eager staff to help you along.

Considering that "space" is one of those words that occupies a page of the dictionary to cover all the subtly different definitions (that no native speaker will ever consult!), I'm not at all surprised to see it take on a new figurative meaning. To me, the "room... esp. considered in terms of its function" seems to me a good candidate for producing such a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing that comes to mind that could be related is the relatively new word *hackerspace*.  Here's Google's definition for reference:

> A hackerspace (also referred to as a hacklab, makerspace or hackspace)
>   is a community-operated, often "Not For Profit" (501(c)(3) in the
>   United States), workspace where people with common interests, often in
>   computers, machining, technology, science, digital art or electronic
>   art, can meet, socialize and collaborate.

I'm unsure of when this word came into vogue or what may have preceded it, but the use of *space* in your example is similar.  They are talking about a community consisting of everyone who is interested in such things and collaborates on related work.